# how to interpolate the given name of a variable into a string?

Tags: ruby

EDIT: Apologies, perhaps this wasn't clear.  The issue is not with getting the `player` object to respond to the attribute - I want to return the *name* of the attribute (eg, `uid`, `external_uid`, `name`, `birth_date`, etc) in the message string, not the value.

I'm trying to refactor some tests and I have a method that looks like this:

```
 def assert_frozen(player)
    assert_predicate player.uid, :frozen?, 'uid is not frozen'
    assert_predicate player.profile.external_uid, :frozen?,
      'external_uid is not frozen'
    # etc, etc, for all of the attributes
 end
```

I'd like to make something similar to this:

```
def assert_frozen_attribute(player_attribute)
  assert_predicate player.player_attribute, :frozen?, 'PLAYER_ATTRIBUTE is not frozen'
  # if the uid were not frozen, this should return "uid is not frozen"
end
```

Is there a way to interpolate the name of the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
assert_predicate player.public_send(player_attribute), :frozen?, "#{player_attribute} is not frozen"
```

Comment: @dax attribute name (instead of its value) will be interpolated in string, so both answers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this, you could either pass a string `'uid'` or a symbol `:uid`(which is preferred) as the attribute.

```
def assert_frozen_attribute(player_attribute)
  assert_predicate player.send(player_attribute), :frozen?, "#{player_attribute} is not frozen"
end
```

Comment: this will return the value of the attribute, will it not?

Comment: @dax yes, your code example return the value of attribute too, no?

Comment: @dax In the string will be the attribute name, not value.